# JointJS - Using 'when:' in Inspector inside list

Tags: jointjs

I'm building an Inspector dynamically based in a JSON. However, I can't get `when:` working. Imagine that: I'm inside a list of `object`'s called `list`, and I got three objects: `type`, `rule` and `script`.

- `type` is a `select-box`, which values `rule` or `script`.
- `rule` is a `text`
- `script` is a `text-multiline` (custom type)

I need to show `rule` only if `type` is equals to `rule`, and show `script` only if `type` is equals to `script`. How can I do that? I tried to add to to `rule` the following `when:`:

```
when: {eq: {"type": "rule"}},
```

And a similar one to `script`:

```
when: {eq: {"type": "script"}},
```

However, the Inspector seems to ignore that, and never show them, nor `rule`, nor `script`. How can I make that condition work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JointJS inspector is very limited, and was only giving me problems. I've replaced it with a custom made inspector, made with AngularJS, HTML5 and SASS. In case anyone is having the same trouble, that's my advice: it's much easier to create an inspector from scratch than trying to use JointJS's inspector.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work with a bit of testing. I actually found the inspector pretty good - especially the conditional hiding/showing does work even for large set of different properties.
The problem might be in the way you reference the property. In my case, something like this worked:

```
text: {
         type: 'content-editable',
         label: 'Simple text input',
         when: {
               eq: {
                     'attrs/type/text': 'SIMPLE_COMPONENT'
                   }
                 }
       }
```

I am setting the attribute type at some other place using element.attr() function:

```
element.attr({type: {
                text: 'SIMPLE_COMPONENT'
            }});
```

BTW: Also managed to "configure" the Inspector dynamically from large JSON containing definitions of various elements/components.